# Probable Bug in tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITablViewController and implementing the following :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.oldIndexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

NSLog(@"%@", indexPath);
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
self.oldIndexPath = indexPath;
}
```

What I notice is, the checkmark appears on 2 cells, one with index path, for example, if I select a cell with index path `{length = 2, path = 0 - 2}` and scrolling down I notice the checkmark is also visible on `{length = 2, path = 0 - 14}`

There is just 1 section in the table view and around 18-19 rows.

Can somebody verify this for me / or is it time for me to get some sleep :/ ?

P.S : tested this on simulator and device

The cells are created as follows :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{ 
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell"; 
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath]; 
// Configure the cell... 
cell.textLabel.text = self.stationsDictionary[@"urls"][indexPath.row][@"title"]; 
return cell; 
}
```

Comment: this looks like a bug in rowForRowAtIndexPath method, you're probably doing something wrong when creating the cells

Comment: This is how I'm creating the cell : ````
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    
    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = self.stationsDictionary[@"urls"][indexPath.row][@"title"];
    return cell;
}````

Comment: i think you should check on visible cell before call cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: move the code in your question please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your cells are reusable (I suppose), you need to set this in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.oldIndexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    NSLog(@"%@", indexPath);

    self.oldIndexPath = indexPath;
    for (UITableViewCell *cell in tableView.visibleCells) {
        if ([tableView indexPathForCell:cell].section == indexPath.section && [tableView indexPathForCell:cell].row == indexPath.row) {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    // Configure the cell... 
    cell.textLabel.text = self.stationsDictionary[@"urls"][indexPath.row][@"title"]; return cell;
    cell.accessoryType = self.oldIndexPath.section == indexPath.section && self.oldIndexPath.row == indexPath.row ? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

Or the reused cell will keep the state of the previous cell (the one reused) which can be checked.

Common error ;)

Comment: Bang on ! This solution is perfect !

Answer (score 1):

When you dequeue a cell from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, be sure to reset its status - in your case, the `accessoryType` property.

Since cells are reused, what happens is that when cell with index 2 is not visible, it is reused to display row with index 14.

As a consequence of that, you need to save each cell state if you want to preserve its status (in your case in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` if you only need to save the `accessoryType` property), and restore into the cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.
You can use an `NSArray`, using the cell index as array index, to save your cell status, or even a "normal" array of `UITableViewCellAccessoryType` or booleans